# Sequential reading of a json format

Tags: php, json

I have this json content inside a var in php:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1977103383661",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "MUM Invasion Photos",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2117387&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1977103423662",
         "privacy": "friends",
         "count": 1,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2011-05-06T12:21:30+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-05-06T12:21:30+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1954051927389",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Milan",
         "location": "Milan",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2115307&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1954052447402",
         "privacy": "friends",
         "count": 26,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2011-04-25T11:58:14+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-05-07T17:18:10+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1875623126718",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Wall Photos",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2108888&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1875623166719",
         "privacy": "everyone",
         "count": 1,
         "type": "wall",
         "created_time": "2011-03-28T02:43:54+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-03-28T02:43:54+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1832680213172",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "PhotoAge for iPhone\u00ae",
         "description": "\"PhotoAge for iPhone\u00ae\" por Percipo Inc. Haciendo computadoras mas humano...",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2106226&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1832680293174",
         "privacy": "friends",
         "count": 3,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2011-03-05T18:18:09+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-03-05T18:20:52+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1718288673455",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Camera+ Photos",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2097024&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1718288753457",
         "privacy": "friends",
         "count": 2,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2010-12-26T22:38:52+0000",
         "updated_time": "2010-12-26T22:39:14+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1716820796759",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Galaxy Tab Contest",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2096857&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1716827796934",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 5,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2010-12-26T00:50:27+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-01-31T19:46:19+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1688275683149",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Pasantias de la beca",
         "location": "Palermo-Italia",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2094132&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1688275843153",
         "privacy": "friends",
         "count": 45,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2010-12-06T18:27:02+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-03-26T18:56:36+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1595209916563",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Profile Pictures",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2082673&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1579272118128",
         "privacy": "friends",
         "count": 3,
         "type": "profile",
         "created_time": "2010-10-07T16:12:55+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-10T04:17:28+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1219601286582",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Mobile Uploads",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2036068&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1219601326583",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 46,
         "type": "mobile",
         "created_time": "2009-09-13T01:38:31+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-10T04:18:10+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1167780671099",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Nueva vieja tabla",
         "location": "Playa hedionda",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2027360&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1167782391142",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 12,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2009-06-21T01:37:13+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-10T04:19:13+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1104082278679",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Cuya",
         "description": "RLST & SRT",
         "location": "Cuyagua",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2018540&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1104091558911",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 30,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2009-03-01T23:49:23+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-10T04:16:34+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1057859363135",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Boca de Aroa",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2010172&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1057880363660",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 10,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-11-05T01:16:46+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-10T04:16:25+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1051327359839",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "2da mojada",
         "location": "Playa fantasma, via tucacas",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2008928&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1051329159884",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 11,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-10-15T00:58:48+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-10T04:16:15+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1050703064232",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Estrenando tabla",
         "location": "Patanemo",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2008822&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1050705184285",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 13,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-10-12T22:29:46+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-10T04:19:22+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1037750900436",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Surfing Safari",
         "location": "Choroni",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2006692&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1037753740507",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 48,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-08-24T23:28:22+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-05-08T23:56:24+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1032278323625",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "El Acto",
         "location": "Valencia",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2006001&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1037921944712",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 23,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-08-06T02:43:55+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-05-09T00:03:05+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1031740150171",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "LA Marcha",
         "location": "UC",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2005922&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1031754630533",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 33,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-08-04T03:00:19+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-05-07T18:04:21+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1029393851515",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Defensa de la Tesis",
         "description": "20pts!!!",
         "location": "Valencia",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2005543&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1029395531557",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 27,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-07-26T02:27:55+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-05-07T09:03:28+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1021161285706",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Rumbas, Playa y demas",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2004373&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1021163805769",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 52,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-06-17T00:35:03+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-12T03:16:11+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1013076403589",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Solo en Venezuela",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2003189&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1013077843625",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 60,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-05-03T16:58:49+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-10T04:14:03+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1010917109608",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Algunas Varias",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2002900&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1010917909628",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 17,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-04-21T05:53:03+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-10T04:15:01+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1008495809077",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "Solo para el video",
         "description": "Este albun solo es para el video...",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2002571&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1008495969081",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 15,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-04-06T05:32:57+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-06T21:32:12+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1008464688299",
         "from": {
            "name": "Domingo Sarmiento Lupo",
            "id": "1125405534"
         },
         "name": "PhotoShop",
         "description": "Algunos trabajos de PhotoShop. Sugerencias?",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2002568&id=1125405534",
         "cover_photo": "1041428912384",
         "privacy": "custom",
         "count": 42,
         "type": "normal",
         "created_time": "2008-04-05T23:00:03+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-05-09T21:08:06+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=2227470867|2.AQCF2qmOAjCq-I1Y.3600.1305979200.0-1125405534|4Fni91SEYdaFvpF5AscYzuVBwEg&limit=25&since=1304684490",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=2227470867|2.AQCF2qmOAjCq-I1Y.3600.1305979200.0-1125405534|4Fni91SEYdaFvpF5AscYzuVBwEg&limit=25&until=1207436403"
   }
}
```

I want to echo every ID and NAME from each block, but Im very new at json and i always get stuck when i need to read more than one data. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show how the JSON object is being transferred into a PHP variable and how it looks there.

Comment: That’s not valid JSON. In valid JSON, [`/` needs to be escaped inside strings](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2.5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumed your shown JSON object is assigned as that to a JS variable `o` and you want to loop in JS:

```
for (i = 0; i < o.data.length; i++) {
    alert(
        'id = ' + o.data[i].id + '\n' +
        'name = ' +  o.data[i].name  + '\n' +
        'from.id = ' + o.data[i].from.id + '\n' +
        'from.name = ' +  o.data[i].from.name
    );
}
```

Assumed your shown JSON object is assigned as that in a PHP string variable `$s`:

```
$aObject = json_decode($s, true);
foreach ($aObject['data'] as $i => $a) {
    echo
        'id = ' . $a['id'] . "<br />\n" .
        'name = ' . $a['name'] . "<br />\n" .
        'from.id = ' . $a['from']['id'] . "<br />\n" .
        'from.name = ' . $a['from']['name'] . "<br /><br />\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, only saw the JSON notation, which is not possible to define it this way in PHP.

Comment: Updated my answer, added PHP loop.

Comment: Thelen, beat me , +1 for being fast and accurate

Answer (score 1):

btw which **id** and **name** u r talking about: inside `data` or inside `data.from`

### Javascript way

```
var jsondata = {"data": [{ // given string }]};

for (var i=0; i<json.data.length; i++) {
  document.write("<hr/><b>"+i+"</b><br/>");
  document.write("Data ID=>" + json.data[i].id+";Data Name=> " + json.data[i].name + "<br/>");
  document.write(i+"From ID: " + json.data[i].from.id+";From Name:" + json.data[i].from.name );
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/HW4j8/5/)

### PHP way

```
$decodejson = json_decode($jsondata, true);
foreach ($decodejson ['data'] as $k => $v) {
echo
        'id =>' . $v['id'] . "<br />\n" .
        'name => ' . $v['name'] . "<br />\n" .
        'from.id =>' . $v['from']['id'] . "\n" .
        'from.name => ' . $v['from']['name'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: @jurgen Thanks :) where i need to modify?? i didn't get u

Comment: Your code is correct. What I meant was that both of our answers were nearly at the same time (close to each other). I'm not a native speaker, please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php