# How to select json item from the array

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

From the below JSON, how can I retrieve title from the note and notes using a for loop and ajax to retrieve?

```
{
"infos": {
        "info": [
        {
            "startYear": "1900",
            "endYear": "1930",
            "timeZoneDesc": "daweerrewereopreproewropewredfkfdufssfsfsfsfrerewrBlahhhhh..",
            "timeZoneID": "1",
                            "note": {
                "notes": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "title": "Mmm"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "title": "Wmm"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "title": "Smm"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "links": [
                { "id": "1", "title": "Red House", "url": "http://infopedia.nl.sg/articles/SIP_611_2004-12-24.html" },
                { "id": "2", "title": "Joo Chiat", "url": "http://www.the-inncrowd.com/joochiat.htm" },
                { "id": "3", "title": "Bake", "url": "https://thelongnwindingroad.wordpress.com/tag/red-house-bakery" }
            ]
        }
```

I tried out the code below but it doesn't work - it either says:

> is null
>
> not an object
>
> length is null
>
> r not an object

```
var detail = eval(xmlhttprequest.responseText)
var rss = detail.infos.info
for(var i = 0; i<rss.length; i++)
   startyear += rss[i].startyear
```

Comment: i answered similar question some day before, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081062/sequential-reading-of-a-json-format/6081294#6081294

Comment: @diEcho not really the same...cause the json data that this article is there no array within the array

Comment: Where in the code you posted are you trying to access the title? What is `i`?

Comment: i don't how to access the title, i want to access the title in the json data i given above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    alert(JSON.infos.info[0].note.notes[i].title);
}
```

TRY IT HERE: [JSFIDDLE WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/krmby/Y9Cyj/)

BTW your JSON is not valid. Use this JSON:

```
var JSON = {
    "infos": {
        "info": [
            {
                "startYear": "1900",
                "endYear": "1930",
                "timeZoneDesc": "daweerrewereopreproewropewredfkfdufssfsfsfsfrerewrBlahhhhh..",
                "timeZoneID": "1",
                "note": {
                    "notes": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "title": "Mmm"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "title": "Wmm"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "3",
                            "title": "Smm"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "links": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "title": "Red House",
                        "url": "http://infopedia.nl.sg/articles/SIP_611_2004-12-24.html"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "title": "Joo Chiat",
                        "url": "http://www.the-inncrowd.com/joochiat.htm"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "title": "Bake",
                        "url": "https://thelongnwindingroad.wordpress.com/tag/red-house-bakery"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

Here is what you want:

```
var infoLength= JSON.infos.info.length;

for (infoIndex = 0; infoIndex < infoLength; infoIndex++) {

    var notesLength= JSON.infos.info[infoIndex].note.notes.length;

    for (noteIndex = 0; noteIndex < notesLength; noteIndex++) {

        alert(JSON.infos.info[infoIndex].note.notes[noteIndex].title);

    }
}
```

Comment: my json data is put in the json file so i must retrieve from the file...the var JSON = eval(xmlhttprequest.responseText) ...does it work the same..cause i got to use something like this

Comment: `var JSON = eval ( xmlhttp.responseText );` yeah it works the same. Just be sure the response is valid and parse-able.

Comment: @krmby if i want to loop within the length instead of what you show me the number 3, how should i do?

Comment: @krmby it say that JSON.infos.info.note.notes.length is null or not an object

Comment: @Cutex: Because `info` is an array, not an object. You have to access it with an index.

Comment: It would be better to just store the whole `notes` array in a new variable. You also should not shadow `JSON` which is an object provided by newer browsers.

Comment: @Felix Kling Thanks for Global JSON warning.@CutexBabies just use a different variable name than JSON.

Comment: @krmby if i have to more than one array in the "info" how should change the code..cause my "info" i have the same attri like the json data i show, but now the "info" have more than one array

Comment: @Cutex: If this works, then [@Gary's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107039/how-to-select-json-item-from-the-array/6107080#6107080) should have worked too (because it is basically the same). If `info` contains more than one element, then you need another loop to iterate over it. So in the ended you will have a nested `for` loop.

Comment: @CutexBabies updated answer with an nested loop. Also check JSFiddle link

Comment: var notesLength= JSON.infos.info[0].note.notes.length; and this JSON.infos.info[infoIndex].note.notes[noteIndex].title);
this code right it only display the title of first  array of the "info"...can i change the 0 to something else

Answer (score 2):

Well the "path" to the JSON `notes` array-like object is:

```
json.infos.info[0].note.notes;
```

So you could do something like:

```
var notes = json.infos.info[0].note.notes;
var titles = [];
for (var i = 0, len = notes.length; i < len; i++)
{
   titles.push(notes[i].title);
}

alert('titles is: ' + titles.join(', '));
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/uDxqD/

---

Are you using jQuery? ;-)

```
// Assuming your using "success" in ajax response
success: function(json)
{
    var titles = $(json.infos.info[0].note.notes).map(function() {
        return this.title;
    }).get();
    alert(titles.join(', '));
}
```

Comment: No the question is, where did YOU get *tat* json.

Comment: no i not using jquery, i also never use push?where do you get the json from??

Comment: @Gary that json i have to retrieve from the ajax and in the json data file...so basically i must retrieve from the json file and put retrieve the title of the note array? i try this way 
var detail = eval....
then for loop it
inside should be
var start year=""
startyear += ...[i].startyear
then this way but the title in the note array don't

Comment: @Cutex: What is your problem now? The answer should work fine. `json` is just the name of the variable that contains the data. You have to use the name you use in your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Putting your json into an var called `obj`, use the following:

```
obj.infos.info[0].note.notes[0].title
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Znq34/

Comment: i try something like this
var detail = eval....
then for loop it
inside should be
var start year=""
startyear += ...[i].startyear...then how should do it for the title, the obj will change right for what you given me

Answer (score 0):

First count the length of notes

`var len = jsonobject.infos.info.note.notes.length;`

Then loops through and get

`var title = jsonobject.infos.info.note.notes[i].title;`

Comment: can show me more specific? which do you get the jsonobject?
is it from the var jsonobject = eval(xmlhttprequest.responseText)...do you get your jsonobject from here?

Comment: I simply tried 
`var jsonobject = eval(your json);` 
It is same if you are getting that json from Ajax response like 
`var jsonobject = eval(xmlhttprequest.responseText)`; 

In any case you have to create json object and then use as I explained before.