# How to decode JSON format using PHP?

Tags: php, json, decode

I have following JSON format I am receiving. I want to decode that in PHP. But I am unable to find how can I get the data within DATA key in following format.

JSON:

```
firedAt => Thu, 05 Feb 2015 20:00:13 GMT
event => orderPaid
data => [
  {
    "id": 10263410,
    "total": 219.00,
    "shipping": 0.00,
    "status": {
      "id": 2578171,
      "title": "Betalning mottagen",
      "color": "#c0ffc0",
      "is_paid": true,
      "is_delivered": false,
      "is_active": true
    },
    "note": null,
    "order_id": 10187,
    "deleted": false,
    "updated": null,
    "created": "2015-02-05 21:33:18",
    "reminder_sent": false,
    "market": 10,
    "market_reference": "47335091",
    "new": true,
    "integration": 274029,
    "weight": "0",
    "deliver_date": null,
    "rows": [
      {
        "id": 9086694,
        "quantity": 1,
        "title": "Mobilskal 62613-BRU",
        "reference": "62613-BRU",
        "price": 219,
        "market_reference": "26971426",
        "tax": "25",
        "created": "2015-02-05 21:33:18",
        "product_id": null,
        "integration": 274021,
        "vat": 43.8
      }
    ],
    "customer": {
      "contact": {
        "id": 934714,
        "alias": "Jane Doe",
        "email": "jane@doe.com",
        "phone": "0812839183",
        "mobile": "0721231234"
      },
      "address": {
        "id": 934714,
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe Svensson",
        "address": "Kungsgatan 6",
        "address2": "",
        "zip": "37450",
        "city": "Asarum",
        "country": {
          "name": "Sverige",
          "code": "se"
        }
      },
      "invoice": {
        "id": 934714,
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe Svensson",
        "address": "Kungsgatan 6",
        "address2": "",
        "zip": "37450",
        "city": "Asarum",
        "country": {
          "name": "Sverige",
          "code": "se"
        }
      }
    },
    "history": [
      {
        "id": "4457827",
        "created": "2015-02-05 21:33:18",
        "message": "Ny orderrad: 1 st Mobilskal 62613-BRU"
      }
    ],
    "icon": [  
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Some of that's JSON, the first bit isn't, so that's not going to decode.

Comment: If you have a good JSON (no syntax errors) you can use this. json_decode($JSON, true);

Comment: So there is no way to decode?

Comment: @VincentToonen Problem is I am unable to get data within DATA key. How can I find that? After that I can use json_decode.                                                    HEre is the link from where I am geting response: https://sello.io/en/developers/webhooks/

Comment: You can not find it yet because its not valid json

Comment: This is valid json. {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}

Comment: This is a helpfull link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107039/how-to-select-json-item-from-the-array

Comment: maybe you can share the code that generates this information

Comment: We would need to see how you are decoding this in order to work out what is wrong. Would you edit this question to include the full runnable code that you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
json_decode($JSON['data'], true);
```

OR

```
$array = json_decode('{
"id": 10263410,
"total": 219.00,
"shipping": 0.00,
"status": {
  "id": 2578171,
  "title": "Betalning mottagen",
  "color": "#c0ffc0",
  "is_paid": true,
  "is_delivered": false,
  "is_active": true
},
"note": null,
"order_id": 10187,
"deleted": false,
"updated": null,
"created": "2015-02-05 21:33:18",
"reminder_sent": false,
"market": 10,
"market_reference": "47335091",
"new": true,
"integration": 274029,
"weight": "0",
"deliver_date": null,
"rows": [
  {
    "id": 9086694,
    "quantity": 1,
    "title": "Mobilskal 62613-BRU",
    "reference": "62613-BRU",
    "price": 219,
    "market_reference": "26971426",
    "tax": "25",
    "created": "2015-02-05 21:33:18",
    "product_id": null,
    "integration": 274021,
    "vat": 43.8
  }
],
"customer": {
  "contact": {
    "id": 934714,
    "alias": "Jane Doe",
    "email": "jane@doe.com",
    "phone": "0812839183",
    "mobile": "0721231234"
  },
  "address": {
    "id": 934714,
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe Svensson",
    "address": "Kungsgatan 6",
    "address2": "",
    "zip": "37450",
    "city": "Asarum",
    "country": {
      "name": "Sverige",
      "code": "se"
    }
  },
  "invoice": {
    "id": 934714,
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe Svensson",
    "address": "Kungsgatan 6",
    "address2": "",
    "zip": "37450",
    "city": "Asarum",
    "country": {
      "name": "Sverige",
      "code": "se"
    }
  }
},
"history": [
  {
    "id": "4457827",
    "created": "2015-02-05 21:33:18",
    "message": "Ny orderrad: 1 st Mobilskal 62613-BRU"
  }
],
"icon": [  
]
}', true);
```