# PHP/JSON Array display values based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, arrays, json

Having a difficult time trying to suss this out. I've searched through, but I'm not sure if the phrase I'm using to search is correct or not.

I have a JSON file that I'm using to bring in an array of data from an outside source. Using PHP, I decode the contents. I've created a dropdown box that will display the keys, but what I'm looking to do now is dynamically populate a printout with the different values that the keys are attached to based on what the select box has selected.

```
    <?php
  // JSON string
  $json = file_get_contents("showrace.json");
  $races = json_decode($json, true);
?>
    <select id="raceSelect">
      <option value="select one" selected>Select One</option>
      <?php foreach($races as $key => $value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value['race'] ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <div id="template">
        Str Plus: #   Dex Plus: #   Wis Plus: #   Int Plus: #<br>
    </div>
```

And here is a sample of what the JSON file looks like:

```
{
"Ithorian":{"price":0,"wis":3,"str":2,"lck":0,"int":2,"frc":0,"dex":-2,"con":2,"cha":-3,"app":"No","hp":1200,"ac":0,"race":"Ithorian","lang":"ithorian"},
"Weequay":{"price":1000,"wis":-2,"str":3,"lck":0,"int":-2,"frc":0,"dex":0,"con":2,"cha":-3,"app":"No","hp":1350,"ac":0,"race":"Weequay","lang":"weequay"}
}
```

In the first snippet, the #'s in the template div will be outputs for the JSON values such as "str" and "dex" and such. While I was able to find out how to set the select to draw in the keys from the JSON, I am baffled at how to populate the template portion with the corresponding values, based off of the selected item.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you get started, as it is not fully fleshed out for everything. But it covers some basics you could use.

First off you would want an onchange handler in your jquery. This will fire off everytime someone changes their choice with the :

```
$("#raceSelect").change(function(e){
    // magic will go here (see further below)
});
// or
$("form").on("change","#raceSelect",function(e){
    // magic will go here (see further below)
});
```

Next up you would want to have access to all that json data in your jquery area to use for displaying those values based on what they chose:

```
<script>
    // define this in your php page output near the top 
    // or within your jquery .ready block
    var jsonData = <?PHP echo $json;?>;
</script>
```

Now you are ready to do some of the magic with the onchange. Accessing the right array in the jsonData, with the id chosen, you can swap out spans and divs to your hearts content. A combined example is as follows:

```
<?PHP
// your php script
$json = file_get_contents("showrace.json");
$races = json_decode($json, true);
?>

<!-- your form here as you have it in your example -->

<div id="template">
    Str Plus: <span id="dat_str">#</span>   Dex Plus: #   Wis Plus: #   Int Plus: #<br>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // this is your jquery .ready block

    var jsonData = <?PHP echo $json;?>;

    $("form").on("change","#raceSelect",function(e){
        var race = $(this).val();
        $("#dat_str").html( jsonData[race].str );
        // you can set the dex, and wiz, etc as well
        // following the same format to assign
    });
});
</script>
```

*Disclaimer: I hand typed this out, and didn't vett or test it. Its purely an example of pieces that should hopefully help you out.*

Comment: Thanks for the help, Randall! I'm a litle dense right now - what's goes in the 'magic' porton?

Comment: Further below, I show a single example of the 'magic will go here'. Basically, you get the race chosen, then reference the jsonData to swap out spots on your page with things like strength, health, dexterity etc.

Comment: Sorry, I also appeared to have assumed you were using jquery for your javascript front end... if you are not, then I apologize for using jquery js examples.

Comment: No, that's fine! I actually didn't have any js on the page at all, so jquery is fine. I just haven't worked with it much. For some reason, it's not pulling correctly, so I'm trying to troubleshoot now. I have the script src in the header for jquery, and the var jsonData up there.

Comment: I added a little more clarity. The assignment of var jsonData is javascript, just in case you were thinking it was pure php variable define. That could make things go bonkers ;)

Comment: I'm still coming up with nothing. I'm starting to think it might have something to do with how my JSON file is set up. Running a quick print $json['Ithorian']; (with .str attached and without) through php returns nothing but a {. I'd assume this would be able to print it if it was correctly formatted?

Comment: Try `print_r($json);` Instead. And we may be hitting our limit on comment discussion for this ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157021/discussion-between-xerakon-and-randall).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using JS

```
var raceSelect = $('#raceSelect').find(":selected").text();
```

and check out this link on how te select from json
then print what you want
[select from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107039/how-to-select-json-item-from-the-array)